# Borrowed value doesn't live long enough, trying to expose iterators instead of concrete Vec representations of the data

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I have a struct representing a grid of data, and accessors for the rows and columns. I'm trying to add accessors for the rows and columns which return iterators instead of Vec.

```
use std::slice::Iter;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Grid<Item : Copy> {
    raw : Vec<Vec<Item>>
}

impl <Item : Copy> Grid <Item>
{
    pub fn new( data: Vec<Vec<Item>> ) -> Grid<Item> {
        Grid{ raw : data }
    }
    pub fn width( &self ) -> usize {
        self.rows()[0].len()
    }
    pub fn height( &self ) -> usize {
        self.rows().len()
    }
    pub fn rows( &self ) -> Vec<Vec<Item>> {
        self.raw.to_owned()
    }
    pub fn cols( &self ) -> Vec<Vec<Item>> {
        let mut cols = Vec::new();
        for i in 0..self.height() {
            let col = self.rows().iter()
                        .map( |row| row[i] )
                        .collect::<Vec<Item>>();
            cols.push(col);
        }
        cols
    }

    pub fn rows_iter( &self ) -> Iter<Vec<Item>> {
        // LIFETIME ERROR HERE
        self.rows().iter()
    }

    pub fn cols_iter( &self ) -> Iter<Vec<Item>> {
        // LIFETIME ERROR HERE
        self.cols().iter()
    }
}
```

Both functions `rows_iter` and `cols_iter` have the same problem: `error: borrowed value does not live long enough`. I've tried a lot of things, but pared it back to the simplest thing to post here.

Comment: You might find the multiarray crate useful. It supports 2D arrays and allows you to create column and row views (shared and mutable) which double as iterator.

Comment: Thanks @sellibitze. I'll check out out, but I'm learning and trying to write these things from scratch for now

Answer (score 2):

You can use the method `into_iter` which returns `std::vec::IntoIter`. The function `iter` usually only borrows the data source iterated over. `into_iter` has ownership of the data source. Thus the vector will live as long as the actual data.

```
pub fn cols_iter( &self ) -> std::vec::IntoIter<Vec<Item>> {
    self.cols().intoiter()
}
```

However, I think that the design of your Grid type could be improved a lot. Always cloning a vector is not a good thing (to name one issue).

Comment: You are right about the implementation. My plan was to write something simple that works, then improve it. A custom iterator will probably be better - and might not have the problems that I ran into here.

Answer (score 1):

Iterators only contain borrowed references to the original data structure; they don't take ownership of it. Therefore, a vector must live longer than an iterator on that vector.

`rows` and `cols` allocate and return a new `Vec`. `rows_iter` and `cols_iter` are trying to return an iterator on a temporary `Vec`. This `Vec` will be deallocated before `rows_iter` or `cols_iter` return. That means that an iterator on that `Vec` must be deallocated before the function returns. However, you're trying to return the iterator from the function, which would make the iterator live longer than the end of the function.

There is simply no way to make `rows_iter` and `cols_iter` compile as is. I believe these methods are simply unnecessary, since you already provide the public `rows` and `cols` methods.

Comment: I was intending to remove `rows` and `cols`,  and just expose iterators.

Comment: If I use `self.rows().into_iter()` it actually works. I had previously tried this, but couldn't find a stable supported version of `IntoIter`, which I have now found in `std::vec`.

Comment: And I see your point. `into_iter` is only working because of the `Copy` constraint - which is mainly there because of previous wild stabs in this direction.